# babel wrongly transpiles export default function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, webpack, babeljs

I'am attempting to create a stateless functional component in react, but it looks like babel is having some trouble transpiling. The snippet `export default AppLayout = () => {};` is transpiled to `exports.default = AppLayout = function AppLayout() {};` which gives the following error `Uncaught ReferenceError: AppLayout is not defined`.

I am running babel with the following presets `stage-0`, `es2015` and `react`. I have used this syntax in meteor, so I am guessing its a module I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should also work

```
const MyComponent = () => <div>Hi</div>
export default MyComponent;
```

or a one liner

```
export default () => <div>Hi</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, how come I cannot one-line it

Comment: By not giving a name : export default () => <div>Hi</div>